# Recommended circuit for LVCMOS output to AD9531

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, schematics, lvcmos

I am designing a clock circuit to drive AD9531. Output of clock is LVCMOS 10%-90% vdd (vdd is 3.3v).

Output characteristics:
[image]
LVCMOS output character.

and the AD9351 is as input to get 1.25 -1.75 with 0.5vpp.

What's the expected circuit needed for matching ad9531 input to LVCMOS output?[image]

Comment: Ahmed Salman - Hi, Note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference (i.e. source name & link) for each image & remember to include references in future. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules differ from typical forums).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the very short rise time and the larger output voltage swing than required by the load, I would source terminate with series 50 ohms (adding a 33 ohm resistor to the 17 ohm output impedance) and load terminate with 50 ohms parallel. Connect with a 50 ohm trace. That will attenuate your signal to 1.65v. I didn't see if there was a max signal level spec, but a safe option would be attenuation to 200mV peak to peak, which you can do with a 50 ohm matched resistive attenuation network.

Make sure to include the capacitor for AC coupling.

Comment: thanks for quick response. 
1-yes you are right about 33ohm + 17ohm for output of LVCMOS 
2- to match AD9531 i used formula for  RP = 50 × VDD2 / (VDD1-VDD2)

where RP is parallel resistor to output load. VDD1=LVCMOS amplitude at output .VDD2 is receiver amplitude needed (which is 1.25-1.75 with 0.5Vpp * if im not wrong).

with above formula it gives 107ohm of rp to get 1.5v at output.

Comment: I would use a T attenuator so you don't generate reflections.

Comment: i am trying to figure out output requirement of (1.25-1.75 with 0.5Vpp) when LVCmos gives 10% -90% of VDD.
can you give some hint.

Comment: Are you sure about 0.5vpp? You screen shot suggests 200mV is typical and 500mV would not work on a 1.8v rail.

Comment: yeah . i agree that 200mV is suggested. 
so from LVCMOS 2.64-0.4 V to input as 1.5-1.7 with 200mv actual requirement. 
you think best to deal with it??

Comment: I think the solution in my answer is the best option.

Comment: you mean T-attenuator?

Comment: Any 50 ohm attenuator will work, but T is simple and you can find calculators for it online.

Comment: how to keep between output to1.5-1.75 so it in range for AD??

Comment: You don't have to do that if you AC couple.

Comment: The DC offset for the clock signal should be about ~1.5 volt, so output is ~1.25 volts to ~1.75 volts with 0.5V peak-to-peak.

what that exactly mean??